# Subversion diff : Can't specify revision

Tags: svn

I have a directory 'data', like this:

```
$ svn info data
...
Revision: 666
...
```

So we can see that it is managed by Subversion, and is at revision 666. Now I would like to see the changes between two specific versions (i.e. which files below this directory have been changed between revisions):

```
$ svn diff data@648 data@649
```

Now I get an error, that data@648 were not under version control. It seems that svn doesn't interpret 648 as revision information.

I checked the man page for svn diff, and it explicitly mentions the form

```
 diff PFAD-ALT[@REVALT] URL-NEU[@REVNEU]
```

What did I do wrong?

Comment: The `@`'s work with full URLS, you might like to run `svn diff -r648:649 data` (or: `svn -c 649 data`).

Comment: So the information given by `svn diff --help` seems to be wrong, as it explicitly allows simple pathes as well! BTW, your solution works, but my goal was to see just the **names** of the files, which are different between those revisions, but not the changes themselves. Is this possible too?

Comment: It might be to do with the _translation_ of your help: in English here, it explicitly states: `OLD-TGT and NEW-TGT may be working copy paths or URL[@REV]`, not `working copy paths[@REV]`.

Comment: Wlll... Actually, switching to `LANG=en` yields a different help text (it doesn't use OLD-TGT, but says `diff OLD-PATH[@OLDREV] NEW-URL[@NEWREV]`), but now I see that the German text doesn't claim "PFAD-NEU", but says "URL-NEU". Hence, the translation help was right, but my reading of it was sloppy!!!! Thanks for helping.